# Emacs csharp-mode, definition is void: set difference

Tags: emacs

I'm setting up Emacs, and I'm trying to install csharp-mode for it. I have the .el file located in: `~/.emacs.d/plugins`, but according to [The Github page, it should automatically load after package-install csharp-mode, which it doesn't.](https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode#usage)

`Symbol's function definition is void: set-difference` - is the whole message I get when I try to eval-buffer with `require 'csharp-mode`. Anyone got any idea why this doesn't work?

[image: Screenshot of Emacs]

Comment: This is Emacs bug. I sent workaround PR. https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/pull/50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `set-difference` is defined in the `cl` package, which is included in Emacs but isn't loaded automatically.  Require the `cl` package before `csharp-mode`:

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'csharp-mode)
```

<del>Also report a bug in `csharp-mode`: it should take care of this for you.</del> syohex already [sent a pull request](https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/pull/50) to fix this in csharp-mode.

Comment: That did indeed fix it. Thank you so much!